# Is there a way to do "cookie splitting" using Google Cloud Run for A/B testing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, ab-testing

I see with Cloud Run there is a way to "Manage Traffic", where you can serve different versions of your app to different percentages of your users. But as far as I can tell, the user will get a random version every time they hit refresh (based on the percentages you allocate each version).

With App Engine, you can serve the same version to the same user every time, either using their IP address, or using cookies ([see here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/splitting-traffic)). I'm just wondering if there is a way to achieve the same thing using Cloud Run, without me having to migrate my app over to App Engine.

I have read a bunch of articles, but I only seem to be able to randomly serve different versions of the app using Cloud Run.

Comment: Have you checked this documentation on [using tags for testing, traffic migration and rollbacks for Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#tags)?